# Boilerplate project for MERN stack?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, node.js, mongodb, react

I have an elementary knowledge of the MERN ecosystem, that is to say that I have successfully created simple CRUD applications using Express JS, React JS, Redux and MongoDB with Node JS and Webpack. I only have a basic understanding of what Docker is. Then I came across [MERN IO](http://mern.io/) which offers boilerplate project that gives a head start on building React apps.

Are there any other boilerplate projects for MERN stack to build scalable web apps? Which would be the best one among those for me given the above facts and

If not, could MERN IO a good boilerplate project to start building scalable web applications?

Comment: @Izzy i guess the question is on-topic now as per the site guidelines. Can the on-hold flag be removed?

Comment: I'm not a dev, so I don't have the required insight – but doesn't this lack some requirements? What features should the boilerplate offer? "Any other" sounds a bit broad to me. As I cannot tell, I'll reopen this now and leave it to other devs (who might vote to put it on hold again – or point out what details are missing). Good luck!